# How to organize git workflow to fix bugs and introduce new functionality simultaneously

Tags: c++, git

I will give a very simplistic example of real workflow. Please, imagine that it is very complex and consumes a lot of time to think about (approximately the whole day). I will give example in c++, but chosen language is not important for this question.

---

Let imagine this is the whole project in single file:

```
#include <iostream>
int sum(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
int main() {
    std::cout << sum(4, 0) << '\n';
}
```

The aim of this project is to print sum of '4' and '0'.

Now I want to introduce new functionality in project: find product of 
'5' and '6' and then add to the result '7'. At the end of the day I want to make commit `git commit -m "Result of 5 * 6 + 7"`. Ok, I start with the following:

```
#include <iostream>
int sum(int a, int b) { return a - b; }
int product(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
int main() {
    std::cout << sum(4, 0) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum(product(5, 6), 7) << '\n';
}
```

I spent a couple of hours implementing this functionality and now want to test it. Unfortunately, the result is wrong: 23 instead of 37. After another couple of debugging hours, I've found a bug in `sum` function:

```
#include <iostream>
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int product(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
int main() {
    std::cout << sum(4, 0) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum(product(5, 6), 7) << '\n';
}
```

Now program is correct, however fix of that complex bug requires own commit. I am too lazy, so I join both commits into the single `git commit -m "Result of 5 * 6 + 7"`.

---

I want to **hold sequence of commits clear, so that we can easily find what have done and when**. I want to be able to easily find an answer when the bug is fixed and distinguish it from implementing something.

The question is **what is the exact sequence of git commands** to support clear sequence of commits during development? For me, clearest way would be to firstly make a commit `git commit -m "Bugfix in sum"`:

```
#include <iostream>
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int main() {
    std::cout << sum(4, 0) << '\n';
}
```

And the second commit which introduces functionality is `git commit -m "Result of 5 * 6 + 7"`:

```
#include <iostream>
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int product(int a, int b) { return a * b; }
int main() {
    std::cout << sum(4, 0) << '\n';
    std::cout << sum(product(5, 6), 7) << '\n';
}
```

The problem is that I've already introduced new functionality and then found a bug, *reversing this process* seems very difficult to accomplish.
I don't know how to efficiently jump between two (or even more) simultaneous paths of program development during the process of implementing new functionality.

Comment: Why do you think the bug should be fixed before the functionality ?

Comment: @user43968 Because 5 minutes after commit my lead can say to me: "Customers just said that this functionality is not needed for them, let's remove the last commit!"

Comment: ok so the question is not about current dev but about mainting old release ?

Comment: @user43968 The idea is to hold sequence of commits clear, so that we can easily find what have done and when. I want to be able to easily find an answer when the bug is fixed and distinguish it from implementing something.

Comment: This would be trivial if you had the habit of always doing new work in a new local branch.

Comment: @super After reading answer of user43968, I see it.

Comment: Reversing is easy. Interactive Rebase in Git clients like SourceTree allows this. Or you can cherry-pick the fixes in order (we usually do did this, rather than Pull Requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap I suppose you have the current working tree:

```
   C1---C2---(5*6+7)---(fixSumBug)---DevBranch
```

But you are saying that maybe a client will need the fixSumBug commit but not the new functionality.

So I suppose you should have a workflow like this one :

```
o---o---o ----(fixSumBug) ---LastRealeaseBranch
         \                    \(merge when bug found)
          F1------F2------F3-----MasterBranch
                            \
                              impl(4+0)----half(5*6)---(5*6+7) --personalDevBranch
```

MasterBranch is the state of the next release with functionality F1,F2,F3 already develop.

You start working on 5*6+7 functionality so you create a new branch from master where you can dev at your own speed and commit half functionality or non working one)

When a client found a bug go back in the branch corresponding to it's release fix this bug and create a new version/patch that you can release.

When the fix is done merge the fix with your Dev/Master Branch. 
You can merge the fix with branch corresponding to other version of the soft.

Now go back to work on your personal branch and finish your feature when done you can squash all your commit into one to have this working tree :

```
 o---o---o -------(fixSumBug)-----LastRealeaseBranch
             \                    \(merge when bug found)
              F1------F2------F3-----O--------------------MasterBranch
                                \
                                  squash(5*6+7) --personalDevBranch
```

Now you can merge your dev with master and delete you personal branch. I recommend to rebase before merge so you get this final tree :

```
 o---o---o -------(fixSumBug)-----LastRealeaseBranch
             \                    \(merge when bug found)
              F1------F2------F3-----O------F(5*6+7)--------------MasterBranch
```

To achieve this result assuming you are on personalDevBranch :

```
git fetch #to get last state of master
git rebase -i origin/master #maybe you have to fix some conflict if other developer change the same file contained in personal dev with option -i you can choose to squash commit into one (find how to use it)
```

Now you are in this state with you branch just ahead master:

```
 o---o---o -------(fixSumBug)-----LastRealeaseBranch
             \                    \(merge when bug found)
              F1------F2------F3-----O-------MasterBranch
                                             \
                                          squash(5*6+7) ---personalDevBranch
```

If everything is ok you can go back to master and merge

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only personalDevBranch #--ff-only ensure a lineare history
git push #if everything is ok
```

Now you can delete you personalDevBranch and start a new feature

*It's a good practice to name personalDevBranch with the name of the feature example feature-sum-567 so other can see what you are doing and even review your code before merging with master but that's an other story..*

Comment: It can be a bit complex than in your example of current working tree. During the implementation, I can make only half of changes, then find and fix the bug, and finally finish implementation. So there is no possibility to make separate commits with `impl->bugifx` or as `half impl->bugfix->finish impl` (because those revisions is not working at all), but it is possible when bugfix comes first, and then implementation is put on top of it: `bugfix->impl`.

Comment: Bug fix and impl are Always 2 separate commit/dev no ? I'll update my answer for the complete use case

Comment: The idea with merging seems the right tool to solve the problem, but I find it a lot more harder than simply join everything in single commit. It is very difficult to enforce developer to use this style of workflow. Could you please provide a simple example of git commands during work process?

Comment: Excellent answer, this is exactly what I am looking for. Could you clarify when I should introduce `savemywork`? And how to incorporate `fixSumBug` in `personalDevBranch` before pushing to master, because I want to be sure that my implementation is correct (without unfixed bug it is not correct)?

Comment: forget about save my work it represented a commit that you can do. I was thinking about the situation where you need to go (end of the day and you are in a dummy state but you want to save it anyway) you can commit it any way

Comment: and some details

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you use a tool called [Gitflow](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) and the branching model from [Vincent Driessen](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). It's a really awesome model to manage complex projects with ease.